# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'trans_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, paypal

I got this error while I'm trying to finish the payment processing from payPal:

> **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'trans_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `transactions` (`amount`, `sender`, `type`, `currency`, `description`, `fee`, `client_id`, `status`, `receiver`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1.00, sb-9gnps5116369@personal.example.com, paypal, USD, Your transaction description, 0, 1, approved, sb-eftqj5115088@business.example.com, 2021-02-19 23:11:39, 2021-02-19 23:11:39))**

**Connection.php:**

```
E:\laragon\www\thepaymentss\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

 * @param  array     $bindings
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\QueryException
 */
protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
{
    // To execute the statement, we'll simply call the callback, which will actually
    // run the SQL against the PDO connection. Then we can calculate the time it
    // took to execute and log the query SQL, bindings and time in our memory.
    try {
        $result = $callback($query, $bindings);
    }

    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Log a query in the connection's query log.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  array   $bindings
 * @param  float|null  $time
 * @return void
 */
```

The error of "**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'trans_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `transactions` (`amount`, `sender`, `type`, `currency`, `description`, `fee`, `client_id`, `status`, `receiver`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1.00, sb-9gnps5116369@personal.example.com, paypal, USD, Your transaction description, 0, 1, approved, sb-eftqj5115088@business.example.com, 2021-02-19 23:11:39, 2021-02-19 23:11:39))**" is at line:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
```

Can someone explain and help me why isn't it working?

Comment: Did you added `trans_id` on `fillable` property?

Comment: Can you guide me how can I add trans_id on fillable property? because I'm new to Laravel @user15070659

Comment: add your model data

Comment: if your ``trans_id`` is your table ``primary_key`` id, make it ``autoincerment``

Comment: I just put them together like: 

**protected $fillable = [ 'names', 'email','contact', 'password','secret_key','trans_id','amount','sender','type','currency','description','fee','client_id','status','receiver', ];**

 I put it on Client.php, because I found many script with fillable property there, but I still got the same error,  or where do people usually put it spesifically? I mean, it seems like I don't have the model data folder, I have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [mass](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) assignment, you need to define `fillable` property on `Transction` model :

```
protected $fillable = ['trans_id','amount','sender','type','currency','description','fee','client_id','status','receiver'];
```

Comment: I just put them together like: 

**protected $fillable = [ 'names', 'email','contact', 'password','secret_key','trans_id','amount','sender','type','currency','description','fee','client_id','status','receiver', ];**

 I put it on Client.php, because I found many script with fillable property there, but I still got the same error,  or where do people usually put it spesifically? I mean, it seems like I don't have the model data folder, I have no idea

Comment: Let me know your query, how you tried to insert data on your transactions table?